# Create a zip file and download it error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to download some files by creating the zip file on a local-server.  The file is downloaded in zip format, but when I try to extract it, it gives me the error:

> End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not
>   a zip file, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the
>   latter case the central directory and zip file comment will be found
>   on the last disk(s) of this archive.

This is the code I am using for this:

```
function download_gallery($id) {
        $this->load->library('zip');

        $path = '/uploads/post/' . $id;

        $this->zip->read_dir($path, FALSE);
        $filename = $id . '.zip';

// http headers for zip downloads
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header('Content-Type: application/zip'); // mime type
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"'); // tell browser what's the file name
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); // no cache
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path, $filename));

        // Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"
        $this->zip->download($filename);
    }
```

I checked the values of all variables which are being passing into the function, and all are fine.

I'm using codeigniter for this by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three mistakes.

You never call `$this->zip->archive($filename);` therefore the zip file doesn't exist at any time.

`filesize($path, $filename)` is wrong usage of this function. `filesize` takes only one parameter.

I believe `$this->zip->download($filename);` already setup the required headers for the download, there is no need to do that yourself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the 1st and 2nd mistake. I'm actually trying to download a directory of images there. Thanks for the feedback I'll try to figure out what you've said.

Comment: You tell the zip library what files you want it to zip, but you never tell it to save the zip file somewhere. The zip file you are composing is never actually created. And the filesize, well, just check the PHP manual http://www.php.net/filesize

Comment: I did the zip->archive() thing but i still have that problm. My archive created on the web app folder works fine. just problm with the downloaded version